# Accents in MVC5 controller parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller that looks like this

```
public ActionResult Search(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    ...
    return View();
}
```

When I access /Search?firstname=Hervé the value I get for firstname in my controller is Herv�

Is there a way I can make my controllers accent aware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet `charset` headers aren't set:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

This header needs to be set when you send the request from the client. Also, make sure to turn on `globalization` settings in the Web.config.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization
           fileEncoding="utf-8"
           requestEncoding="utf-8"
           responseEncoding="utf-8"
           culture="en-US"
           uiCulture="de-DE"
        />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkak5b9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you. Setting the requestEncoding did the job.